# How to get previous month water readings values and subtract from current from the same table in mysqli

Tags: mysql

i have table(readings) columns are

```
id|   date|    meter_id|  previous|  current|  units_cons
1  21/04/2019   20          23        25         2
2  23/05/2019   20          25        30         5
3  22/06/2019   20          30        36         6
4  22/04/2019   3           8         10         2
5  27/5/2019    3           10        15         5
```

my challenge is i cannot pull the previous month values,at the current date on my form. when i search the column meter_id

```
$meter_id =$_REQUEST['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT prev,pres,unit_cons,date  
                                  FROM readings where id='$meter_id'");
```

when i run the code i get values for a different meter user.e.g

when i click on meter_id 3 i get values for meter_id 20

Comment: how do you pass the meter_id?

Comment: From the request you are pulling id and calling it meter_id, Then in your sql you are searching on id not meter_id.

Comment: Jason K sorry meter_id= $meter_id

Comment: There is no pres column in that table. you might have to update the query perhaps

Comment: pramodh there is (current)

Answer (score 0):

ensure you are using the right key either `id` or `meter_id` because from your request it reads `$_REQUEST['id'];` be consistent

```
 $id =$_REQUEST['id'];

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT previous, current, (current - previous) AS reading_diff, unit_cons, date FROM readings where id={$id}");
```

**Note** where `reading_diff` is the computer difference between the current and previous meter readings.